# How can I keep samosa pastry crispy longer?

Tags: deep-frying, pastry

I am making samosa (a triangular savoury pastry fried in ghee or oil, containing spiced vegetables or meat). To make outer cover I am making dough using the following:

1. All purpose flour (100 gram)
2. Ghee               (25 gram)
3. ajwain (carom).
4. salt
5. water

To fill the cover I am using potato filling. After deep frying samosas they are nice and crispy, but after some time they become soft. What can we do to make them crispy for a longer time?

Answer (score 3):

Allow the samosas to cool on a rack. If you put the warm samosas on a plate, moisture will build up and create steam. Steam makes fried foods soggy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Samosa dough do become soggy after a while. I found out re-heating in the oven re-gain the crispiness.